# Taylor Series of $e^x$ and the last term

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, power-series

So I was thinking a bit about the Taylor series of $e^x$ which we all know is $$e^x=1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots$$

But what I noticed is that if you want to approximate, and take the last term as odd, the function you get can output negative values, while if the last term is even, then the function only outputs positive values. Now here's the question, since $e^x>0$ for all $x$, does that mean the last term of the series is even?

Comment: There is no "last term" of the series

Comment: But from its expansion, what makes it always positive?

Comment: Can you define your "function" that produces positive or negative values?

Comment: At any $x < 0$, the sum of the positive terms (even $n$) is larger than the absolute value of the negative terms (odd $n$). The positive terms win.

Comment: What happens intuitively is that as you add more and more terms, the positive terms "kill off" the negative terms, leading to a net positive answer. You should notice that for any fixed $x$, if you add sufficiently many terms then the approximation at $x$ will be positive

Answer (score 2):

Just to formalize what you are asking:

- You are considering partial sums (which are finite sums) of the $e^x$ Taylor series
- You note that when $x$ is negative, the term $\frac{x^i}{i!}$ is negative for odd $i$
- You are asking that since if $e^x > 0$ for all $x$, the last term must be even.

No, the last term is very small compared to all the previous terms and so even if it is negative, it is negligibly negative and will not affect the sign of the (finite) partial sum.

Comment: It seems that the OP noted that not only when $x$ is negative, the term $\frac{x^i}{i!}$ is negative for odd $i$, but that the partial sum itself may happen to be negative.

Comment: Hopefully, the OP now realizes that the last term is significantly smaller than the previous term (and sum).

Comment: Only for $x$ close to $0$. For $x$ close to $-\infty$, the last term is not "negligibly negative", and will definitely "affect the sign of the (finite) partial sum".

Comment: @AnneBauval Oh, yeah, it'll do that I guess... until the factorial growth kicks in, as it inevitably will. But yeah, it'll jump around for very negative x because that's far from the Taylor series centre.

Answer (score 0):

The truncated series
$$
e_n(x) = 1+\frac{x}{1!}+\frac{x^2}{2!}+\frac{x^3}{3!}+\cdots+\frac{x^n}{n!}
$$
is a very good approcimation for $e^x$ when $x$ is near $0$.  But a bad approximation when $|x|$ is large.

Here we see $e^x$ (in blue) and $e_{11}(x)$ (in red).
[image: graphs]
Near $0$ they are indistinguishable.  Below $-4$, they are far apart.
In $e_{10}$ they are also far apart, but the red will be above the blue.  So ending at an even term does not help.

Answer (score 0):

If we look at Taylor's Theorem, it talks (essentially) about the size of the error you get by approximating a function by its Taylor polynomials. In particular, it says that

$$f(x) = \sum_{k = 0}^n \frac{(x - x_0)^k}{k!} f^{(k)}(x_0) + \frac{(x - x_0)^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} f^{(n+1)}(\xi)$$

where $\xi$ is a number between $x$ and $x_0$. Or in other words, the error in using $n$ terms is about as big as the $(n+1)$-th term. In the case of $f(x) = e^x$ and $x_0 = 0$, that means that for negative values of $x$ the error is on the order of $\frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$, and when $x$ is a big negative number that's going to be big regardless of whether $n$ is odd or even, the difference is just whether the error is a big positive or negative amount.

In other words, the problem is that the number of terms you need in order to get a good approximation increases as $x$ increases - as a very rough rule of thumb, if $x > n$ then the error is probably going to be really bad, but even for $n \approx x$ it's probably still not great.